# What should replace deprecated Facebook adView setAdListener to get callbacks?

Tags: android, ads, facebook-audience-network

As of v5.6.0 the adView.setAdListener is deprecated. How can we receive onAdLoaded and onError callbacks now?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Solution:** Since 5.6, you should use `loadAd(AdView.AdViewLoadConfig loadAdConfig)`

> ```
> public void loadAd(AdView.AdViewLoadConfig loadAdConfig)
> ```
>
> Loads an ad.
>
> This method always returns immediately. The ad is loaded
>   asynchronously. The control's ad listener will be called when loading
>   finishes or fails.

**Java**

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this, "placementId", new AdSize(width, height));

AdListener adListener = new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {

    }
};

AdView.AdViewLoadConfig loadAdConfig = adView.buildLoadAdConfig()
        .withAdListener(adListener)
        .build();

adView.loadAd(loadAdConfig);
```

**Kotlin**

```
val adView = AdView(this, "placementId", AdSize(width, height))

val adListener = object : AdListener {
    override fun onError(ad: Ad, adError: AdError) {

    }

    override fun onAdLoaded(ad: Ad) {

    }

    override fun onAdClicked(ad: Ad) {

    }

    override fun onLoggingImpression(ad: Ad) {

    }
}

val loadAdConfig = adView.buildLoadAdConfig()
    .withAdListener(adListener)
    .build()

adView.loadAd(loadAdConfig)
```

Find more information [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/reference/android/com/facebook/ads/adview.html/).

Answer (score 3):

**Banner Ad Code: To resolve Issue of setAdListener Method deprecated**

**Replace your setAdlistener() method For Banner Ad Using below code:**

```
 AdView adView = new AdView(context, context.getString(R.string.str_facebook_banner), AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_90);

    AdListener adListener = new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Fb failed :: " + adError.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onAdLoaded: ");

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {

        }
    };


    AdView.AdViewLoadConfig loadAdConfig = adView.buildLoadAdConfig()
            .withAdListener(adListener)
            .build();
    adView.loadAd(loadAdConfig);
```

**Interstitial Ad Code: To resolve Issue of setAdListener Method deprecated**

**You can use below code to replace setAdListener() method for Interstitial Ad:**

```
    InterstitialAd  interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context, context.getString(R.string.str_facebook_interstitial));

    InterstitialAdListener interstitialAdListener = new InterstitialAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInterstitialDisplayed(Ad ad) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onInterstitialDismissed(Ad ad) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Fb failed :: " + adError.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onAdLoaded: ");
            interstitialAd.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {

        }
    };



    interstitialAd.loadAd(interstitialAd.buildLoadAdConfig()
            .withAdListener(interstitialAdListener)
            .withCacheFlags(ALL)
            .build());
}
```

**Official Reference Link:** https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/changelog-android#5_6_0

Answer (score 1):

Your class should implement AdListener.
Refer this link for delailed explanation.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/reference/android/com/facebook/ads/adlistener.html/

Answer (score 1):

```
val interstitialAdFb = com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd(this, resources.getString(R.string.fb_interstitial_id))
    val adListener = object : com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAdListener {
        override fun onLoggingImpression(p0: Ad?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
        override fun onInterstitialDisplayed(p0: Ad?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
        override fun onAdClicked(p0: Ad?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
        override fun onInterstitialDismissed(p0: Ad?) {

        }

        override fun onError(p0: Ad?, p1: AdError?) {

        }

        override fun onAdLoaded(p0: Ad?) {

        }
    }

    val loadAdConfig = interstitialAdFb.buildLoadAdConfig()
            .withAdListener(adListener)
            .build()

    interstitialAdFb.loadAd(loadAdConfig)

    //and when you want to show ad
    if (interstitialAdFb.isAdLoaded)
        interstitialAdFb.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the latest guide updated from here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/support/troubleshoot/integration

For eg:

```
NativeAdListener nativeAdListener = new NativeAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMediaDownloaded(Ad ad) {
            // Native ad finished downloading all assets
            Log.e(TAG, "Native ad finished downloading all assets.");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
        // Native ad failed to load
            Log.e(TAG, "Native ad failed to load: " + adError.getErrorMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
            // Native ad is loaded and ready to be displayed
            Log.d(TAG, "Native ad is loaded and ready to be displayed!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
            // Native ad clicked
            Log.d(TAG, "Native ad clicked!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {
            // Native ad impression
            Log.d(TAG, "Native ad impression logged!");
        }
    };

    // Request an ad
    nativeAd.loadAd(
            nativeAd.buildLoadAdConfig()
                    .withAdListener(nativeAdListener)
                    .build());
```